Quarkus GRPC OpenTelemetry multiple transactions
Im using Quarkus together with io.quarkus:quarkus-opentelemetry:3.15.0. For log collection we are using Elastic and Cabana.
I have been doing some performance tests and I can see 2 types of transactions -> 'POST' and 'GRPC method we are calling' (in our use case its envoy.service.auth.v3.Authorization/Check). The number of transactions done by 'POST' and the GRPC method is the same, but the latency differs. Why is that ? What is the 'POST' method for ?


The gRPC exporter uses HTTP 2 with a POST to export the OTel data.

After some more investigation it seems that the HTTP POST is the initialisation of GRPC connection, since GRPC is using HTTP 2 POST on start of the call. The OTEL implementation has 2 transactions for grpc server -> One for the HTTP 2 POST which happens on the start of GRPC connection and the other one which happens when GRPC call is being done.

It looks that the exporter uses two ways for exporting: OTLP/gRPC and OTLP/HTTP. And the differences in latency means grpc exporter performs faster than the http. In general, grpc is faster.

The Quarkus exporter can only use one of those protocols at a time.
